# Get applicationContext from a KMM module

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I'm currently developing a simple KMM module, which needs `Context` in order to perform some operations. I am aware of ways to achieve that with extending `Application` class and making dependency injection. What am I trying to do right now - to make this module available out of the box with no need to modify `manifest` or make manual injection on start up. I am just wondering is it a bad practice to make something like so:

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
object SomeUtil {

    private val context = Activity().applicationContext

}
```

Since `applicationContext` return the `Context` for the whole app and we're initializing it once will there be a leak? Or are there some other points not to make it?

Maybe there are some other possibilities to get app context from the module? I've seen some examples of retrieving it from threads, but as I understand this will be (or is already) deprecated.

UPD: This causes an error. `Activity()` seems to be `null`. So any ideas how to achieve that without DI and "MyApplication"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common problem in android libraries - how to get the app context without having access to the application codebase? It's why you often init libraries with something like `SharedPrefHelper.init(applicationContext)` in your `Application.onCreate()`

As KMM shared code is a library you get a similar problem. [Android app startup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/app-startup) is an androidx lib built to solve this (as well as improving startup performance).

Rough sample (everything in shared code):

```
// In androidMain
class MySqlDelightInitialiser : Initializer<SqlDriver> {
    override fun create(context: Context): SqlDriver {
        val driver = createDriver(context)
        MyLibraryObject.init(context, driver)
        return driver
    }

    override fun dependencies(): List<Class<out Initializer<*>>> {
        return emptyList()
    }
}

// In androidMain/AndroidManifest
<application>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.sql-delight-initialiser"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:node="merge"
        tools:replace="android:authorities"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="my.package.SqlDelightInitialiser"
            android:value="androidx.startup"
            />
    </provider>
</application>
```

Comment: Looks like you are abusing the library and misusing it. Why "create()" returns instance of "SqlDriver"? Who is gonna use it under the hood? If some methods returns non-void, that means someone should or is using it. If that is the case, we have to use that instance not do something like this "MyLibraryObject.init(context, driver)".

Comment: I edited the sample code with the above suggestion

Comment: Thank you for the edit but few things here. "return Nothing" will throw exception. Also changing from "X" to "Nothing" does not mean we solved the problem :) There must be a reason the Start-Up library returns type instead of void. So if it returns type that means someone should or does use that instance but who and why? Or if that "who" is consumer then how do that consumer gets that instance?

Answer (score 5):

Well, I'd start with saying this isn't really a KMM question. This only applies to the Android code.

As far as I know, no, there's no way to statically, globally get access to the application context without some semi-hacky solutions. This is a long standing problem that doesn't really have a good solution.

Crashlytics does (did?) something weird by registering a ContentProvider who's only purpose is to get the application and make that available. Assuming you're publishing as an aar, it would register the ContentProvider for you.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html

I wouldn't recommend that. I greatly prefer configuring library context init myself, but you can try the ContentProvider route.

Comment: When browsing web I've also found [this](https://github.com/florent37/Multiplatform-Preferences/blob/master/src/androidMain/kotlin/com.github.florent37/preferences/AppContextProvider.kt), which also seems like things muggles should not do. So I'm also looking in DI, which is a bit disappointing

Comment: "Well, I'd start with saying this isn't really a KMM question." How does having different arguments for different platforms is Android specific and not related to KMM?

Answer (score 3):

**This is the simple approach I use.**

I created a simple AppContext object in the androidModule

```kotlin
internal object AppContext {
    private lateinit var application: Application

    fun setUp(context: Context) {
        application = context as Application
    }

    fun get(): Context {
        if(::application.isInitialized.not()) throw Exception("Application context isn't initialized")
        return application.applicationContext
    }
}
```

Created an AppContextInitializer and used AndriodX App startup to provide the context to the AppContext.

```kotlin
internal class AppContextInitializer : Initializer<Context> {
    override fun create(context: Context): Context {
        AppContext.setUp(context.applicationContext)
        return AppContext.get()
    }
    override fun dependencies(): List<Class<out Initializer<*>>> = emptyList()
}
```

You will need to create an AndroidManifest file directly under the androidModule

```xml
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <application>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"
            >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.sample.sharedmodule.AppContextInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup"
                />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

To use the application context in your AndroidModule, you just need to call

```kotlin
AppContext.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Inject it in constructor or as method param:

```
class SomeUtil(private val context: Context) {
   ....
}

object SomeUtil {
   fun someMethod(context: Context) { .... }
}
```

Context (but also Activity, Application, Service) instances are created and destroyed by Android framework and creating instances manually (or mocking) will probably work at compile time, but they will cause exceptions at runtime